# Analysis of TV station preferences for various demographic groups

Tags: python, performance, matrix, pandas

I have a notebook [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/mburke05/f9ba86c2af67f286f4c0ac163ba5cbfc) which details my code and may be more legible.

I worked on a project that flattens a table that initially looked like this (this is **table1**):

```
18+fem  18+male date    station
17118   15925   12/1/2014   ADSM  
16006   11379   12/2/2014   ADSM  
19259   18846   12/3/2014   ADSM  
16386   17068   12/4/2014   ADSM  
7329    23158   12/5/2014   ADSM  
15893   13021   12/6/2014   ADSM  
59688   36299   12/1/2014   AEN   
61738   67912   12/2/2014   AEN   
61115   30988   12/3/2014   AEN   
50751   29726   12/4/2014   AEN   
73939   47329   12/5/2014   AEN   
147652  54407   12/6/2014   AEN
```

Into the table that is in the linked notebook which looks like this (this is **table2**):

```
        65+fem  65+male
ADSM    48.6    3.2
AEN    -20.4   -22.4
```

By section of code here is what I am doing:

**1: Importing dependencies, importing files, joining them together to create table1 view.**

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import os


allFiles = glob.glob(os.getcwd() + "/*.csv")

df_list = []
for files in allFiles:
    filename = os.path.split(files)[-1].split('.csv')[0]
    df = pd.read_csv(files, names=["date","station", "impressions"], encoding="utf-8-sig")
    df['new_index'] = df[['date', 'station']].apply(lambda x: '_'.join(map(str, x)), axis=1)
    df = df[['new_index','impressions']]
    df.set_index('new_index', inplace=True)
    df.rename(columns={'impressions' : filename}, inplace=True)
    df_list.append(df)
df = pd.concat([frame for frame in df_list], axis=1)
df = df.reset_index()
df['date'] = df['new_index'].apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[0])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%Y-%m-%d")
df['station'] = df['new_index'].apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[1])
del df['new_index']
df.sort_values(by=['station', 'date'], inplace=True)
```

**2: Creating a temp dataframe, this will house the values that I calculate in the next step and become our heat map table.**

```
heat_df = pd.DataFrame(index=df.station.unique(), columns=list(df.columns[:12]))
```

Finally, this is where performance really becomes brutally slow (~10-15seconds.)

**3: Creating table2**

```
#for each station in our table1

for station in df.station.unique():

    #13 is the number of columns of our demographics (18+fem, 18+male, etc.; of which there are 13 total), hence xrange(12), I think this could or should have been accomplished by using something better referencing the columns by name rather than by index. 
    for i in xrange(12):

        #create a temp dataframe. there is a pre and a post section. i am going to compare the post to the pre in the below maths. 
        pre = df[(df.station == station) & 
                 (df.date >= datetime(year=2014, day=2, month=12)) &
                 (df.date <= datetime(year=2015, day=22, month=3))]
        post = df[(df.station == station) & 
                 (df.date >= datetime(year=2015, day=1, month=12)) &
                 (df.date <= datetime(year=2016, day=20, month=3))]

        #this is where things get funky. i am time adjusting the dataframe so that the days of the week line up (12/2/2014 is a tuesday, and 12/1/2015 is a tuesday, so i create a new index that is the number of days since each of those respective starting points.) i call this column 'delta'.
        pre['delta'] = pre['date'].apply(lambda x: x - datetime(year=2014, day=2, month=12))
        post['delta'] = post['date'].apply(lambda x: x - datetime(year=2015, day=1, month=12))

        #i zero in on the column(which represents one demographic) i'm looking for; i.
        post_join = post.set_index('delta')
        post_join = post_join[[i]]
        pre_join = pre.set_index('delta')
        pre_join = pre_join[[i]]

        #create a temp dataframe called 'calc' that is just the delta as an index, and the specific demographic 
        #i then create a column 't' which is used to calculate the % change +/- year over year, adjusted by the delta column. 
        calc = pd.concat([pre_join, post_join], axis=1)
        calc['t'] =((calc[[1]] - calc[[0]])/((calc[[0]])))*100

        #the single point calc.t.mean() is then finally entered for each demographic, and station combination. 
        heat_df.set_value(station, df.columns[i], calc.t.mean())
```

I'm hoping to get input on my general code, any mistakes or redundancies I might be committing to error. Performance improvements. And just general theory improvements (i.e. how would you adjust this problem if you needed the same sort of transformation of the data.)

Comment: For the benefit of reviewers, could you briefly summarize _what_ the transformation is from table1 to table2, and make that your question title? See [ask].

Comment: Im honestly not sure how to describe what the transformation is which is why I spent so much time trying to flesh the code nuances out so that they made sense. Do you have suggestions? I think maybe it's like a shifted pivot transformation. But not sure. Sorry if that doesn't help.

Comment: I've edited the title as a suggestion. Perhaps you could do even better than that.